# javascript add unnecessary white space to start of toggled class / end of original class

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to develop a very simple, add / toggle class method, which is similar to **jQuery**'s `addClass()`, and `toggleClass()` methods.

However, I have come across a minor issue where, the method will work great initially, but after the first add / toggle, there will be added white space in **front** of the new class (or **behind** the original class).

For **example**:

```
<!-- initial toggle / add (this is what I wanted everytime) !-->
<div class="firstclass toggledclass"></div>

<!-- after initial toggle, THEN the new class is removed (this is what I'm left with) !-->
<div class="firstclass "></div>

<!-- after initial toggle / add (when I add a new class back in again) !-->
<div class="firstclass  toggledclass"></div> 
<!-- and so on... !-->
```

This **obviously** isn't how it is supposed to function, but I cannot figure out a way to fix it without breaking my `script`.

---

Here is my (relevant) **JavaScript**:

```
// add class
for(var i = 0; i < this.element.length; i++){
    if((" " + this.element[i].className + " ").indexOf(" " + classes + " ") < 0){
        this.element[i].className += " " + classes; // i feel the problem retains here
    }
}

// toggle class 
for(var i = 0; i < this.element.length; i++){
    if(this.element[i].classList.contains(classes)){
        var regex = new RegExp("(^| )" + classes + "($| )", "g");

        for(var i = 0; i < this.element.length; i++){
            this.element[i].className = this.element[i].className.replace(regex, " ");
        }
    } else {
        if((" " + this.element[i].className + " ").indexOf(" " + classes + " ") < 0){
            this.element[i].className += " " + classes; // and here
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still pretty new to **JavaScript**, so most of this has been made from altered `scripts` I have found (I wanted to stray away from `classList` new methods `.add()`, `.toggle()` e.t.c...) from forums.

If anyone could help me figure out how to solve this problem / improve this block of code, it would be **greatly** appreciated,

Comment: I don't understand well what you are trying to do.
You just want to add a class if the element doesn't have it, and remove it if it already have it ?

Comment: Is this a purely academic exercise?

Comment: @AymDev for the toggle method... yes.

Comment: Why are you using `classList` for some things but not for others? `Element.classList.toggle` already exists!

Comment: @Scimonster yes, I'm attaching it to learning how to use **JavaScript** `objects` :-)

Comment: @lonesomeday isn't the `toggle()` method **HTML5** dependant?

Comment: jQuery i'm sure uses `classList` under the hood, not by modifying the `className` string. There's nothing wrong with some extra spaces here. But if you want, you could trim it and remove any double spaces.

Comment: @GROVER. No. The whole of `classList` is unsupported in certain browsers, along with a specific aspect of `toggle` in others. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist).

Comment: @Scimonster haha yeah, It's not that it wouldn't work, it's just that, it's not how it is supposed to function. And if you put it within an interval, eventually you'll end up with `class="intialclass  space space space space                                   newclass"`.. (apologies for the word "space", it will not let me put more than one) If that makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe instead working with whitespaces directly try to get all classes into array and work on array. It would work

```
var classStr = el.getAttribute('class');
var classes = classStr.split(" ");
```

And after pushing class to array do the join method.

so if you for example want to add new class to the array I would firstly look if class isn't there already with

```
if(classes.indexOf("class") == -1) {
classes.push("class");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Kejt! Mind showing me how to implement it? :) Apologies if it seems a bit obvious, but I'm still learning vanilla **JavaScript**

Comment: That example doesn't really help me, haha.. I mean like, show me how to implement it within my code?